# Have I found a paradox, or is the universe digital? Or am I just plain wrong?

Tags: logic, probability, universe

If the universe is analog, there must exist an infinite number of positions. This raises an interesting question.

Let me boil it down to something familiar: a table and an ashtray. I'll let the ashtray be square, just for convenience.

In an analog universe, the table alone contains an infinite number of locations on its surface. No matter which two points you select, you'll always be able to point out a location between them. Like the way there are infinite rational numbers between any two rational numbers, unequal to each other.

We imagine the table is 50 x 50 cm, and we say the origin (0,0) is at the lower left. If I put the ashtray on the table, at a random position, what is the probability that it ends up with its lower left corner at the exact coordinate (10,10)?

According to other answers regarding infinity and probability I've found on the web, the chances of hitting a certain position out of a quantity containing an infinite number of positions, is zero.

The problem is that all positions on the table have the same probability. That means the probability for the ashtray to hit any position on the table is zero.

Nevertheless, obviously it is possible to place an ashtray on a table. So, in spite of a zero possiblity, one position is chosen anyway. This cannot be!

If the universe is digital (so a minimum distance exists no matter how small), there is no problem at all: the table contains a finite number of positions, all have the same probability greater than zero of being chosen at random, and one of them is selected when I set down the ashtray.

I remember Max Planck concludes something about the radiation of energy, because an object would radiate equal amounts of energy on all wavelengths, and since there are an infinite number of wavelengths, all objects would radiate infinite energy. This could not be true, so Planck concluded that the energy of atoms could only have discrete values.

So, does my example prove the universe to be digital?
Or, is the universe analog, and this is a paradox?
Or does my logic fail somewhere?

Comment: Take a prob&stats class.  One of the first things you'll learn is that "probability=0" isn't the same thing as "can't happen".

Comment: no its not zero its an epsilon

Comment: This is a math question, not a philosophy question. Math models our world; that doesn't mean it *is* our world.

Comment: We don't know if spacetime is continuous or discrete, we don't have a complete picture of quantum gravity. Spacetime in classical gravity (GR) is continuous, but quantum mechanics tells us that it needs to be discrete at the Planck scale, so we know that those two theories can't be the only story. Our current best models of QG, string theory and the like, are even more confusing because it isn't clear whether or not spacetime is discrete or continuous in them, because they are not fully realized theories. So it's not that you've found a paradox, we just don't know the answer yet.

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times on the physics SE, see for example [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33273/is-spacetime-discrete-or-continuous) and all of the relate and linked questions. I have to agree with the above commenter, though, this isn't really a philosophy question because it's something that is clearly within the realm of physics with active research being done on it. Like I said, it's not a paradox; physics just isn't where it needs to be yet, but it's close.

Comment: @user It _is_ zero. But that doesn't mean it can't happen.

Comment: The paradoxical analysis of Planck's black box doesn't assume "equal amounts of energy on all wavelengths", but it does produce an answer suggesting an infinite amount of total energy.  And Planck concluded results only about heat radiation, not atoms.

Comment: Related: https://youtu.be/tQSbms5MDvY

Comment: I thought this too. Nice to see the idea out in the wild.

I agree fully with your reasoning; it seems likely that at least one of either space or time is discrete because otherwise - paradox.

The top answer right now points to something I don't know called Newton's Integral Calculus as a get-out, but doesn't explain it in a way that I understand - if anyone could edit that answer to point to an explainer of NIC and why that ducks the paradox, that'd be a great help to me.

Comment: @piersb https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuity/ "Newton's integral calculus" just means doing calculus the way that Newton did, i.e. treating differentials as fluxions and integration as the reverse of differentiation (fundamental theorem of calculus), as opposed to Leibniz's calculus which treats infinitesimals as actual infinitesimals. Deltas and epsilons versus nonstandard numbers. If your issue is with what calculus and integration is, I don't think you'll find someone who can explain all of that in just one edit to a tangentially but not really related question.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was hoping for a pointer to an idiots guide. I'm not a mathematician, so mentioning calculus and integration as an answer to a philosophy question without a link to the context of how it's relevant wasn't helpful to me.

Comment: You might consider saying "discrete" rather than  "digital,"  and say "continuous" rather than "analog."  Analog and digital are modes of _processing_ signals, whereas "continuous" and "discrete" are different branches of mathematics such as might be used for studying the laws of nature.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely

Comment: You mean "discrete." "Digital" would mean that we're living in the Matrix.

Comment: I edited some parts out of this question, because it was already quite long enough and generally on SE sites we do not include these kind of conversational parts in our posts. In other words, posts are encouraged to be stripped of as much 'fluff' as possible (such as thanks, which you can do by upvoting posts, or greetings / taglines). Anyway, enjoy the site.

Comment: In the world of quantum mechanics, analog != continuous. As it turns out, even [space itself may be discrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length).

Comment: congratulation, you are on your way to discover calculus!

Comment: Your error is that you consider that 0 × ∞ = 0. This is simply not true. If something can't happen in a finite number of attempts (because of zero probability), it still can happen when the number of attempts is infinite.

Comment: It can be both, as well with points (events) that exist discretely in space-time having any distance separating them. Position and time are extremely relative concepts when considering this kind of question, look up the idea of 'action' to get a clearer idea of the structure of space-time.

Comment: Plank's constant implies a fundamental minimum distance: `Plank length`. So yes the physical space in the unit can **not** be infinitely divided up. A photon can travel a distance measured in multiples of `Plank length` (not a fraction of a plank length).

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I would counter that it is not zero since atoms have a finite size (in our current models).  Just because atoms are small to us doesn't mean they don't have a size.  Ditto for quarks, etc.

Comment: @user28502 purely mathematically, in the standard setting of probability the probability that a continuous random variable takes any particular value is exactly 0, even though it will certainly take some value when realized (this is because the Lebesgue measure of a point is 0). If that seems unsettling, which is reasonable, one can use probability measures taking values in non-Archimedian fields like the hyperreals so that possible events always have non-zero probability (so your epsilon could be an infinitesimal). But again, this is all just about the math and not about any physical reality

Comment: @CramerTV "Finite" means "not infinite"; you mean that atoms have nonzero size. But the size of atoms is irrelevant: the question is about the location of atoms. Our current theoris of space and matter allow atoms to be anywhere in a continuum of positions.

Comment: Basically, either you go the physics way or the mathematics way. In the former, there isn't a satisfactory model of microspace yet, so we don't know (and Planck length isn't the answer to everything). In the latter, calculating probabilities with infinite sets makes no good sense, unless you use *measures*.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Re "...would mean living in the Matrix": But we almost certainly do. Of course not in the trivial sense of the movie, but in the sense of a reality which is one way or another calculated. It seems pretty obvious. (Note that "calculated" does not necessarily imply "deterministic" or, more philosophically, "predestined". Laplace's Demon would know no more than Heisenberg.)

Comment: At a certain degree of accuracy of measurement the ashtray doesn't even have a fixed position, it has vibrating atoms with diffuse clouds of electrons surrounding them; same for the table... If that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that all positions on the table have the same probability. That means the probability for the ashtray to hit any position on the table is zero.

Not quite. The probability for the ashtray to hit any **given** position on the table is zero. But as you have observed, you can most certainly lay the arrow on the table and get a **new** position.

> Nevertheless, obviously it is possible to place an ashtray on a table. So, in spite of a zero possibility, one position is chosen anyway. This cannot be!

Since you are not targetting a **given** position, there is no paradox. There is zero probability that you will pick up the ashtray and put it back down at the exact same **given** location, but you can certainly put down the ashtray and get a **new** position, just like you did the first time.

Comment: I am choosing this as the answer, since I think the statement of not targeting a given position nails it.
When I think about it, in a lottery you have very poor chance of getting the right seven numbers out of 50 or whatever pool you can choose from, but making the drawing of the numbers is no problem: It will be a '100%' chance, that you draw seven numbers.
The table example is just a lottery with infinite pool, and placing the ashtray is a 'drawing of a position' among them all.

However, I want to thank everybody who participated, with answers and comments, I became a lot wiser.

Answer (score 68):

You have re-found a well-known paradox -- Zeno's.

This is just a compact version of Zeno's paradox.  Instead of time and space, what you are dividing against one another are two spaces.  The corner has zero probability of ending up anywhere, the same way that the point where Achilles overtakes the tortoise has zero breadth.

In fact, in modern statistical theory the probability of any given point sample from any distribution is almost always zero.  But that works because modern probability theory already presumes a solution to Zeno's paradox.

The normal way out of Zeno's model nowadays is Newton's integral calculus.  From that point of view, any infinitesimal sliver of anything still has zero area, but these zero contributions do add up to nonzero results when accumulated over continuous ranges.

From modern analysis point of view, this is just the nature of space.  Space is continuous so we can always extrapolate values at points from whatever attributes are shared by every neighborhood around them, provided something that consistent exists.  We can compute the sums of areas made up of idealized slivers from approximations that converge to the right shapes.

From the point of view of Nonstandard Analysis, this works because a continuous range involves infinitely many points, and a zero times an infinity can be finite.

More functionally, for any proper measure there is a nonzero uncertainty built into the means of measurement.  In order for Newtonian mechanics to really work for you, you need to give a tolerance for any measure, a zero tolerance often just automatically creates a misleading zero or infinite answer because nothing real is absolutely specific.

Comment: Probably worth emphasising, Zeno's Paradox is a misnomer - it is not a paradox at all. It was just believed to be a paradox by people who predated Newton's Integral calculus

Comment: I don't agree.  Paradoxes that motivate huge systems that work around rather than through our intuition are legitimate arguments.  Zeno and Kant were not wrong to declare this an ultimately unsolvable problem -- but that doesn't mean it has to stand in our way.  Crafty solution like the Zermelo-Frankel axioms or the notion of fluxion that underlies the calculus do not make the weakness or conflict in intuition go away.  They papers over the weakness with a mass of conventions that preserve some parts of the intuition and abandon others.

Comment: We are better off embracing the paradox and all of its potential workarounds than choosing one as a solution, declaring the problem solved, and never considering it any further.

Comment: I must disagree though I can't downvote here. Zeno's paradox is fundamentally different since it is about potential infinity rather than actual infinity which is what the OP has problems with here. You correctly point out the trouble with tolerances but your mixing in of nonstandard analysis doesn't make much sense. It doesn't change anything about the probability (you won't get the the probability of a given point being some infinitesimal it will just be zero). The real issue is that probability over infinite spaces is weird if you expect it to behave normally. Tolerances are the way to go.

Comment: @DRF Exactly what on earth do you think a tolerance is, other than a cutoff for an integral over a probability distribution across a range?  So since tolerances involve integration as part of their definition, introducing integration is not 'mixing in' anything.  It is the idea of the integral that lets us make sense of this whole problem.  And integration no longer officially involves infinitesimals, but IMHO it makes very little sense without them.

Comment: I wasn't arguing against integrals (those are obviously an integral part of any continuous probability distribution) but non standard analysis is just confusing this imo. Also what do tolerances have to do with integrals? Tolerances are the empirical reason that argues for the continuous probability distribution being the way to go, I don't see what they have to do with integration other than being the interval over which you integrate your density function to get the probability, but you can really just as easily use the induced measure.

Comment: "Space is continuous." What about the Planck length? (I'm a bit confused about whether this question is philosophy or physics.)

Comment: @TRiG - I'd say It is both, but questions about the nature of time and space are usually filed under metaphysics since these are not pre-theoretical empirical phenomena but an interpretation of experience.

Comment: It's the "[dartboard paradox](https://www.google.fr/search?q=dartboard+paradox)" (not Zeno's paradox).

Comment: @TRiG  I don't mean physical space, I mean Euclidean space.  Both quantum physics and relativity tell us we are wrong about space, but we still have to start from a certain genetic heritage that we embed in our mathematics.

Comment: @jobermark  Ah, so it's mathematics! ;) Fair enough.

Comment: @TRiG  if the (kind of excessive) response to this answer is right.  One cannot read the OP's mind, he might still choose a different answer, if I have guessed wrong.  I have answers that I consider true masterpieces of logic and composition that got half this score.  And this one is kind of lame. 
 It even lacks any attempt at references.  I do not undersand this forum at all.

Comment: Zeno's paradox (which this is not) is indeed a paradox. What it isn't is an antimony or contradiction.

Comment: @TRiG, the planck length is just that, a pretty arbitrary length (with the nice attribute that if you multiply/divide all those numbers together, like plank length, gravitational constant and speed of light, you end up with "1", but that's just a mathematical trick to make all that stuff easier to work with). It is not an absolute minimum for anything in the "real" universe; and it is not clear that the universe is pixelated to the planck length, either. In fact, nobody knows if the universe "knows" about that constant at all.

Comment: This is not Zeno's paradox.

Comment: "From the point of view of Nonstandard Analysis, this works because a continuous range involves infinitely many points, and zero times an infinity can be finite." This is at least badly phrased if not false. The hyperreal numbers contain 0 just like the real numbers, and any infinite hyperreal multiplied by 0 is still 0 -- that follows directly from the field axioms.

Comment: From the POV of Los theorem, an infinitessimal is a zero.  So it just depends upon your framing of NA.  I will edit it to 'a zero'.

Comment: @AnoE  According to Greene's "Elegant Universe" a vibrating object of the Planck length cannot get any smaller.  If you decrease its length, you have to increase its vibration, which will increase the space it takes up in a different direction to above this length.  I don't see how that supposedly atomizes space, which people keep contending.  But Wheeler has suggested that it might, and I am a fan of his, so I might just not understand.

Comment: Downvoting because this isn't Zeno's paradox. It's pretty explicitly the dartboard paradox

Comment: @StellaBiderman Two names do not necessarily make for two things.  If you see Zeno's paradox as being about simultaneous division and dimensionless points, rather than about disproving motion, this preserves that paradox, whether or not there is also another way of looking at it.  As I see it, there are several ways of looking at this.  This is not even the best one, just the shortest one to write.  But I don't control what other people think of my work...

Comment: @jobermark, I love that book of Greene's for the approach to this stuff it gives to the layman. Just saying that the jury is still out on the Planck scale.

Comment: Some pedantry: "In fact, in modern statistical theory the probability of any given point sample from any distribution is always zero" -- this is only true for purely continuous distributions. Obviously there's also discrete distributions, but in fact you needn't even be one or the other. There's nothing wrong with a distribution simultaneously having discrete and continuous parts.

Comment: @BenMillwood  I added an almost.  (And just to match the pedantry, even when the whole distribution is discrete, this remains true almost always --
 the measure of the set of points with nonzero point-sample values is zero.)

Answer (score 27):

We run into essentially the same problem almost any time we try to combine the real numbers as described by mathematics with probability theory.

When applying probability theory to something like a coin flip, a die, or a deck of cards, we use what's known as a [Probability Mass Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) to assign a probability value to each possible result.  What's the probability rolling this fair six-sided die will give 3?  1/6.

But as you noticed, this type of probability model doesn't work well when trying to work with real numbers, because there are just too many of them.  Since there are more real numbers even within a min-to-max interval than there are natural numbers, if you try to assign a single non-negative probability to each number in the domain and require they add up to 1, almost all of them will need to be zero.

So instead, when dealing with a domain of real numbers, probability theory normally switches to using a [Probability Density Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).  This function assigns a real value to every possible outcome in the domain, but these values are not probabilities.  Instead, to get a probability from a probability density function, you need to take the integral of the function from a start point to an end point, and this represents the probability the result will be between those points.

For a simple example, a process that generates a random real number `x` chosen out of the interval from 0 to 1 such that the likelihood is the same over the entire interval could be represented by the function `p(x)=1`.  The probability of "`x` is between 0 and 1/4" is the integral from 0 to 1/4 of 1, which is 1/4.  The probability of "`x` is *exactly* 1/4", if meaningful at all, would need to be the integral from 1/4 to 1/4 of 1, which is 0.  So even though the probability of any particular exact value is zero, you still have a probability of 1 that the value is somewhere in the interval, and meaningful probabilities for any smaller pieces of the interval you care to calculate.

Real numbers tend to be useful in physics because generally speaking you can divide ordinary quantities of distance, time, mass, and energy into arbitrary intervals (and sometimes non-algebraic numbers like pi and e pop up in the useful models).  Of course as modern science ran into observations now attributed to atoms and photons, and developed the Standard Model of particle physics, we needed new theories that no longer assume mass and energy are indivisible on the smallest (non-ordinary) scales.  Could the same happen for distance and time?  Who knows?

By the way, probability density functions turned out to be rather useful in physics too: basic quantum mechanics describes position and momentum of an object in the form of complex-valued "wave functions" which obey [Schrödinger's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation).  The squares of the absolute values of these wave functions are actually probability density functions for the variable being described.  These wave functions do still assume real-valued position, time, and momentum.

Finally, some of the promising looking ideas about quantum gravity (including string theory) suggest there may in fact be a minimum or fundamental unit of space-time, somewhere around the scale of the [Planck Length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length).  But as far as I've heard, none of these are quite on the level of an established useful theory yet.

Now, all this goes to show that there are ways around the paradox, and ways to still describe our observed universe fairly well using both real numbers and probability.  But that doesn't necessarily imply that's the true fundamental nature of the universe, or anything like that.  It's also possible to construct working physical laws using just rational numbers, or numbers which are all multiples of some single chosen very small number.  (But those systems may not be as easy to calculate with!)  All any physical theory or law can claim is that it does well at explaining and predicting observations, and possibly covers more observations than other theories, and/or is simpler and easier to understand and use than other theories.

So when it comes to questions like: Does the universe truly work this way or that?  or Does a "better" set of physical theories get us closer to understanding a true underlying nature of the universe?  or Why can we predict that things will happen at all?  ... we're into the interesting realm of metaphysics.  But that's another story (and one I'm not so qualified to comment on).

Comment: After reading the question, I ctrl+f'd "planck length" +1 that it is in your answer!

Comment: @MikeOunsworth While the existence of the Planck length may suggest the universe to be discrete in some respects, it isn't necessary to bring in quantum mechanics to find the flaw in the original argument.  The key problem with the OP's argument is that it is assuming that "0 probability" in this context means "cannot happen", where it might be better viewed as the limit of the definite integral of the probability distribution, centered over that point, as the area goes to 0.  For any region with nonzero area, the probability will be greater than 0.

Comment: @Ray I have also taken grad-level statistics courses. Just the phrasing of the question made me think of Planck length as something the OP might be interested in reading about, not that it's necessarily the answer to the question. (after all, isn't the goal to spread knowledge and curiosity, rather than narrowly answering the question as written?) It's amusing that the OP is both wrong and right at the same time, just not for the reasons they believe.

Answer (score 13):

Zeno's Paradox is not a paradox. It is an attack on loose thinking. By emphasising the infinite nature of one thing, and not mentioning the infinite nature of another, it confuses people into thinking something is impossible.

The emphasis, in Zeno's Paradox, is upon the infinite number of times a distance can be subdivided, giving the impression that it will take an infinite amount of time to cross those infinites number of subdivisions. It carefully ignores the fact that every time you halve the distance, you also halve the time it takes to cross that distance (at a given speed). It doesn't matter how finely you subdivide the distance if it always takes the same amount of time to cross all of the subdivisions.

So to the original question - how accurately can you measure the position of the ashtray? The chance of its corner being measured as being at any specified location is dependent on how accurately you can measure it. If you could only measure it to the nearest 10cm, and the table is 50cm square, then there are 25 possible locations, and (assuming random distribution), the probability is 1/25 (0.04). If you can measure to the nearest 1cm, then there are 2500 possible locations, and the probability is 0.0004. And so on. Do bear in mind that Heisenberg's principle puts a lower bound on how accurately you can measure its location (assuming a relatively stationary ashtray!).

In other words, the more accurately you can measure position, the more positions there are, and thus the tinier the probability that your object is occupying a specific one (again, assuming random distribution). The probability is never zero, but it gets very small (but so does the target area).

Another answer said pretty much the same thing by saying that you need to specify a tolerance for position.

In other words, your "paradox" is no more a paradox than Zeno's.

Comment: "Zeno's Paradox is not a paradox. It is an attack on loose thinking." - an attack on loose thinking is what a paradox *is*. ;)

Comment: @AnoE - Such an important point!

Comment: The point about accuracy of measurement is really the true answer.

Comment: @AnoE Well, a paradox (or more precisely, an antinomy) can also show that a chosen set of axioms is not consistent. Such a set may not always be the result of loose thinking.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that probability 0 does *not* mean 'impossible'.

If you have someone flip coins forever, what is the probability that he will *never* encounter a head? Well, it's zero. But it's possible!
In fact, every specific infinite sequence of heads and tails is infinitely improbable; that is, its probability is zero. Still, none is impossible: one of them indeed will happen.

In the same way, the ashtray will land on a point where it had zero probability to land, but that doesn't mean that it was impossible to land there. Indeed it does.

I think this is unrelated to quantum physics telling us distance is quantized. There is a minimum distance you can measure, but that's only a limit on how accurate our instruments can be. It's not like the world is really disposed on a square grid of 1 Planck length, at least to my understanding.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is a fundamental aspect of probability distributions (in Mathematics), i.e. the probability of each point tends to zero, which is why probabilities are calculated on intervals or areas (in case here is [an introduction](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda361.htm)). The smaller the interval the smaller the probability. At the level of a point, it is considered zero. Nevertheless, you can sum it over an interval. Note that this is a mathematical construct.

The more general question is often posed as to whether the "real" universe is *discrete* (I believe it is what you meant as digital) or continous.

You will find here, a [treatment of the exact argument you are making](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/blogs/physics/2015/10/are-space-and-time-discrete-or-continuous/).

Briefly, the idea has long been that matter is composed of *atoms* i.e. indivisible particles. Physics adopted that idea, save that what it thought of atoms were in fact divisible in particles, which were then subdivisible in subparticles, etc..
We are now into a hypothesis of "strings", but to say whether are discrete or continuous, only students of those things would be able to argue about it (but since quantum mechanics relies on probability distributions, we might be back to square one).

There is also the question of whether **space** is itself actually discrete or continuous. Space and time are considered interconnected according to Einstein mechanics.

An important thing to remember is that mathematical constructs and physical models tell us a lot about the **interrelations** among objects, space and time in the physical universe, and about how larger objects can be decomposed into smaller objects. But it doesn't tell us about *what* these things *are*. For all we know, we could have a completely 'wrong' idea of the essence of things, but as long as the theory cannot be faulted and it is applicable, it is good enough.

In the end, it might be a philosophical question on which our science has no definitive answer (in that sense we might call it *meta*physical).

Comment: The probability absolutely is zero. Infinitesimals don't come into it at all. The trick is in how that should be interpreted.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, saying that the probability of a "point" is zero is a shortcut: the point in that context is a limit toward zero of an area; it is then identified with a "point" as a dimension-less object. Hence the confusion?

Comment: In the usual definition of probability as a measure/integral there is absolutely no issue with dimension or anything else. There need be no limit involved (though you could compute it that way) and even if there was you would still get that the value of P(x \in {a})=0 and not an infinitesimal. I see wikipedia has this error as well. When explaining an "apparent paradox". There is no paradox "apparent" or otherwise. The probability measure is only countably additive. This is just the result of most people not understanding infinities yet trying to work with them without rigor.

Comment: Agreed on your point and I amended my answer. If you have power to do so, you are welcome to further amend it.

Answer (score 2):

> According to other answers regarding infinity and probability I've found on the web, the chances to hit a certain position out of a quantity containing an infinite number of positions, is zero.

I think it's sloppy speech about the word "infinity". Your statement is a "divide by zero" error, undefined, meaningless.

I learned in Maths that the correct way to use "infinity" is that it isn't a number, it's a limit ... or more specifically it's no limit, it's unbounded. The definition of "infinity" is "bigger than any number": for example if you pick any number (e.g. "100") I can find another number bigger than your number (e.g. "101"), therefore the number you picked isn't "infinity" ... no number that you can pick is "infinite".

The correct way to phrase your ashtray problem is something like,

- Start with a table
- Put a grid of size "n" on the table
- The number of grid cells is "n squared"
- Therefore the probability of randomly selecting a grid square is "one divided by n squared"
- This formula for probability is true "for all n, even as n tends towards infinity"
- But you can't talk about the probability "when n equals infinity", because infinity is't a number ... infinity is a synonym for "unbounded" or "without an upper bound".

---

The logic of the paradox in the OP depends on "zero multiplied by infinity equals zero" (i.e. zero-probability-per-point multiplied by infinite-points equals a paradox).

You get that equation by doing a division-by-zero, "one divided by zero equals infinity" (i.e. finite-area-of-the-table divided by the size-of-a-zero-area point equals infinitely many points).

But "division by zero" is an undefined operation. Using it results in well-known, trivial (grade-school level), easily recogizable algebraic fallacies, for example as shown here: [Division by zero -- Fallacies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#Fallacies)

It doesn't prove anything about the universe, it's pushing the numbering system until it stalls. You can divide one by n, where n is any non-zero number.

Comment: FTR, it is possible to construct consistent [mathematical frameworks in which infinity _is_ a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis). But it's indeed not the, well, _standard_ way, and whether it's at all sensible to consider ∞ a number is controversial. I personally prefer [constructive approaches](http://paultaylor.eu/ASD/).

Comment: He doesn't say "number equals infinity" but "infinite number of positions". I'd say that is not "sloppy", just a bit shortened. Speaking about infinite sets is not only possible but quite common in maths. For me, it's clear that he is talking about a set of reals in an interval, which is by definition, for any non-trivial interval, an infinite set... and the probability to pick any specific (or actually any subset of finite size) *is* zero. See "measure theory". And this is specifically something different than letting a `n` go to infinity (where each individual step is always finite).

Comment: @AnoE I added a bit to the answer to try to address your comment.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that space actually is analogue (and I'm not sure that that is what contemporary physics tells us), it follows that the probability of any point getting hit is indeed zero.

This, however, is as things should be: No matter how fine-grained your methods of analysis are, if space (or area) really consists of infinitely many infinitely small points, any method of determining the location of the point that got hit must have some sort of uncertainty to it: It will give you the location up to a certain number of decimals, and up to that number of decimals, points in space are discrete: If you measure precisely up to .01 mm, every cm² consists of exactly 100 different discrete locations.

If you do, for the sake of argument, invent a machine that gives you the location with all its (infinite, if space isn't digital) decimal places, nothing is gained, because you will die before you can read off that infinite amount of information, and humanity will go extinct, so there is no meaningful way to say that it has been measured to more than any arbitrary but finite amount of decimal places.

What that means is that we in fact only assume that any point got hit, because we can never find out which point it was. Therefore, to all intents and purposes, it is as if no single infinitely exact point got hit, but only an area of which we can say that a point inside it got hit. So even if space isn't digital, nothing follows from it.

Comment: I think "digital" here was meant as a synonym for "discrete", as opposed to "analog".  You seem to be using it in the opposite sense.

Comment: @aschepler No, I'm using it in the same sense. Did I say anything stupid?

Answer (score 1):

The paradox you mention and Zeno's paradox rely on the irrationality of numbers, which humans invented. I argue, that this irrationality occurs as a result of our current irrationality. My counter example of this is that irrational numbers do not exist in computers. And according to some of the bright minds of today, they say the universe can be computed. So it just may be digital.

Comment: Little nitpick, it works well for rational numbers as well. You don't need irrationality, only infinity.

Comment: Various classes of irrational numbers can be represented just fine in computers.  All algebraic numbers, for example. Or the field extension of the rationals by any finite (computable?) set of irrationals (even if they're transcendental).

Comment: Do irrational numbers exist in our heads? We know of _procedures_ to generate them to some finite number of decimal places, but those procedures can be implemented in computer code.

Comment: @labreuer interesting comment. Can you please hyperlink me to the direction of a peer-reviewed article I may read regarding irrational numbers being used in computers. Please, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In complement to other answers, I'm wondering what conception of probabilities you have to assume for your paradox to go through.

The paradox seems applicable not only to discreteness, but to the idea that the world would have an infinite number of possible configurations more generally. So even if the world is discrete rather than continuous, it is enough that it would be infinite in size (and so could have an infinite number of possible state) for its actual state to have probability zero. But in such case one could be tempted to say that there's no contradiction in the idea that the universe would have a specific state among an infinity of possibilities.

If you assume ignorance probabilities, that would mean that the actual state of the world, or the table in your example, is "unbelievable".  Now we only form beliefs on the basis of our observations and concepts so perhaps conditional probabilities would be more appropriate, but you could obtain the same paradox with conditional probabilities (given that our knowledge is finite). But one could object that what we are disposed to or have reasons to believe is irrelevant to the actual state of the world and that your reasoning is spurious. So you have no reasons to believe that the table is at any specific position, yet it is, but there's no contradiction here.

Assuming nomological probabilities instead of ignorance, the conclusion of the paradox would be that it's nomologically impossible that the universe or the table is in the state it is. But in the case of nomological probabilities, why assume an uniform distribution on possibilities? For example, if the universe is deterministic, there's probability one that it is in its current state given its past state and no paradox ensues, except for the initial conditions of the universe, but why assume that all initial conditions are equally probable? This seems quite metaphysical at this point.

Finally, note that in the case of quantum mechanics, nothing has a perfectly determinate position and probabilities are generally defined over quantified (discrete) possibilities so the paradox doesn't occur, even though space itself is continuous: this is because measurements would be discrete events and would never be of infinite precision (at least in some interpretations).

In any case you raise an interesting paradox having to do with the relation between mathematical formalism and reality. It seems that physics needs continuous space (real and complex numbers, differential calculus) to accurately describe reality, even though our measurements are always discrete, and even though infinities and continuity leads to paradoxes.

Comment: "So even if the world is discrete rather than continuous, it is enough that it would be infinite in size". For the specific problem (placing an object on a table), the thing that matters is that there are infinitely (continuously) many coordinates on that table. Whether the rest of the universe goes to infinity around it does not matter either way. If the "real" universe is discrete, the problem would go away...

Comment: But you have a similar problem. If the universe is infinite you have infinitely many possible configurations of it and the probability of each configuration is zero.

Comment: Sure... the question is not about the state of the whole universe though, but about "local" state (c/f the first question whether there is a "minimum distance", i.e. a pixelization of the universe...).

Comment: Yes. I'm treating the general problem here, the same observations more or less apply to the local case.

Comment: But you're right this wasn't clear so I updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: In fact being infinite is not sufficient for the paradox. Consider the game where I flip a coin repeatedly until I first get tails: there are infinitely many possible outcomes (zero heads, one heads, two, ...), but each has finite probability.

Comment: But every infinite sequence has a zero probability. Or if you flip an infinite number of coins, every result has a zero probability.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I think I have an answer to this, but I can't find out how to write math in this, so bear with me. (And someone please tell me how to format math, can't find it in the formatting help.)

Anyway to the point, I don't necessarily think the chance is zero. Lets start with if you have 10 points then you have a 1 in 10 chance of hitting any individual point. The chance is the reciprocal fraction of the number of points, so 10/1 becomes 1/10. Now infinite points wouldn't technically make 0 chance, it would make the chance be 1/infinity. Now obviously measuring this chance is impossible, but it seems to be a non-zero chance.

If you have *N* points or *N* / 1 the chance of hitting any individual points is 1 / *N*

For any value *N* that is greater than 0 you will have a chance greater than zero. You can raise the value of *N* infinitely while still having a chance to hit a specific point.

That or I really need to work on my math skills.

Comment: For math symbols, see https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3239/2953.

Comment: @Keelan I was mainly looking for a way to do exponents. (10 to the power of -N, as this always gives a non zero number for any value N.) I'll probably use your plugin in the future though since it seems to has some useful symbols.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can use `10<sup>N</sup>` for that. This is also included in the plugin, the fourth symbol on the top row (x-squared / superscript).

Comment: Infinity's not a number, and division isn't defined on it. Instead you should consider the limit of 1/x as x becomes arbitrarily large. This is in fact 0.

Comment: @Canyon How so? With the equation *N* / 1, for any value *N* the reciprocal 1 / *N* is a non-zero number. As you increase *N* you only reduce the number as a fraction, so you can never reduce it to a true zero no matter how infinitely far you proceed. It may be effectively zero for any calculations you might run, but it will not ever truly hit zero.

Comment: That is the problem with infinity: It is purely a thing of definition. And @Canyon is absolutely correct, as this is how things are defined usually. Infinity is not a number, and can only be worked with in context of limits effectively.

Comment: Google "measure theory", it is all about that. Pretty interesting as well.